# Informix Query to EXCLUDE Friday and Saturday of the week & 4PM to 8PM all the days of the week

Tags: sql-server, informix, datepart

I have a requirement to write a Informix Query that will fetch all the records of the table excluding Friday and Saturday of all the weeks and data between 4PM to 8PM of all the days of the week

*Ex:*

If I have the following records in my table

```
Name ProcessStartTime Status

Name1 2017-04-01 17:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Saturday)
Name2 2017-04-02 21:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Sunday)
Name3 2017-04-03 01:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Monday)
Name4 2017-04-04 05:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Tuesday)
Name5 2017-04-05 18:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Wednesday)
Name6 2017-04-05 15:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Wednesday)
Name7 2017-04-06 23:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Thursday)
Name8 2017-04-07 15:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Friday)
```

If I execute the Query I should get the Following records only,

```
Name2 2017-04-02 21:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Sunday)
Name3 2017-04-03 01:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Monday)
Name4 2017-04-04 05:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Tuesday)
Name6 2017-04-05 15:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Wednesday)
Name6 2017-04-06 23:00:02.000 SUCCESS(Thursday)
```

And the remaining data should not fetched because, those records are either Friday or Saturday as well as date time between 4PM to 8PM(Not only Friday and Saturday but for all the days of the week).

I have my SQL Server query here below which is working fine in SSMS,

```
SET DATEFIRST 1

SELECT Name, ProcessStartTime, Status
FROM   @events
WHERE  datepart(DW, ProcessStartTime) NOT IN (5,6)
AND    (datepart(hh, ProcessStartTime) < 16
       OR    
       ProcessStartTime > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, ProcessStartTime), '08:00:00'))

GO
```

but I need to change this Query into Informix Query. I Googled a lot to find the way to get the one but nothing worked. Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Should 20:00:00 be included or excluded?  Is it 'from 16:00 up to but before 20:00'? Or 'from 16:00:00.00000 up to and including 20:00:00.00000'?  Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [Simon Riddle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7630698/simon-riddle)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43661153/), but uses an explicit time range notation:

```
SELECT Name, ProcessStartTime, Status
  FROM Events
 WHERE WEEKDAY(ProcessStartTime) NOT IN (5, 6)
   AND (EXTEND(ProcessStartTime, HOUR TO SECOND) <  DATETIME(16:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND
    OR  EXTEND(ProcessStartTime, HOUR TO SECOND) >= DATETIME(20:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND
       )
```

I prefer this because I think it is easier to tweak it to include/exclude the exact ends of the date ranges that you want.  I think the notation is probably what you want; the `>=` might need to be `>` if events at exactly 8 pm should be included rather than excluded.  Note that the BETWEEN…AND operators include both the end points in the range.

Answer (score 2):

Using this WHERE clause for the query should work:

```
WHERE WEEKDAY(ProcessStartTime) NOT IN (5,6)
AND EXTEND(ProcessStartTime, HOUR TO HOUR)::char(2)::int 
    NOT BETWEEN 16 AND 20
```

A double cast is necessary as there is no builtin cast operation from datetime to integer.

Comment: All the times from 20:00:01 through 20:59:59 are also excluded by `EXTEND(ProcessStartTime, HOUR TO HOUR)::char(2)::int 
    NOT BETWEEN 16 AND 20`